# Unable to access elements Inside a shadow Frame using selenium java

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, selenium

I am trying to access an element which is inside an shadow iframe. I am able to switch to that Frame but while trying to access elements inside it, Getting an Stale Exception.Could any one help on this It would be really grateful. Thanks in advance..

I used below code

```
public void enterCustomerDetails() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement root1 = sfdcSelFW.driver.findElement(By.tagName("sb-page-container"));
        WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);
        WebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.cssSelector("sb-line-editor"));
        WebElement shadowRoot2 = expandRootElement(root2);
        WebElement root3 = shadowRoot2.findElement(By.cssSelector("sb-le-custom-action-services"));
        System.out.println(root3.getAttribute("id"));
        WebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(root3);
        WebElement root4 = shadowRoot3.findElement(By.cssSelector("span>sb-popup#popup"));
        WebElement shadowRoot4 = expandRootElement(root4);
        WebElement root5 = shadowRoot4.findElement(By.cssSelector("sb-dialog"));
        WebElement shadowRoot5 = expandRootElement(root5);
        sfdcSelFW.driver.switchTo().frame(shadowRoot5.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>div.sbDialog>div#content>iframe")));
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        WebElement saveBtnEle =  shadowRoot5.findElement(By.cssSelector(" div.slds-grid input"));
        saveBtnEle.click();
}
```

Here after switching to the frame while trying to executing this step "WebElement saveBtnEle =  shadowRoot5.findElement(By.cssSelector(" div.slds-grid input"));"
It is throwing below exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.101)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 92 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'AKKSR01-7470', ip: '10.135.116.222', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.28.455520 (cc17746adff54984afff480136733114c6b3704b), userDataDir=C:\Users\AKKSR01\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir9256_23445}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=60.0.3112.101, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: b0870cc9bd01750302e3a69fb388ebbf
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value= div.slds-grid input}
```

[Below is the sample snippet for the application and the DOM structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4sNZ.png)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring `shadowRoot5` element to find element inside the frame even after switching to the frame. You should have used the `sfdcSelFW.driver.findelement` instead of `shadowRoot5.findElement` as given below.

```
WebElement saveBtnEle =  sfdcSelFW.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" div.slds-grid input"));
saveBtnEle.click();
```

Full code,

```
public void enterCustomerDetails() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement root1 = sfdcSelFW.driver.findElement(By.tagName("sb-page-container"));
        WebElement shadowRoot1 = expandRootElement(root1);
        WebElement root2 = shadowRoot1.findElement(By.cssSelector("sb-line-editor"));
        WebElement shadowRoot2 = expandRootElement(root2);
        WebElement root3 = shadowRoot2.findElement(By.cssSelector("sb-le-custom-action-services"));
        System.out.println(root3.getAttribute("id"));
        WebElement shadowRoot3 = expandRootElement(root3);
        WebElement root4 = shadowRoot3.findElement(By.cssSelector("span>sb-popup#popup"));
        WebElement shadowRoot4 = expandRootElement(root4);
        WebElement root5 = shadowRoot4.findElement(By.cssSelector("sb-dialog"));
        WebElement shadowRoot5 = expandRootElement(root5);
        WebElement frame =shadowRoot5.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>div.sbDialog>div#content>iframe")
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(sfdcSelFW.driver,30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame);
        WebElement saveBtnEle =  sfdcSelFW.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" div.slds-grid input"));
        saveBtnEle.click();
    }
```

Comment: I tried in that way as well.Then the script throws exception while performing action on it.i.e while executing saveBtnEle.click(); action here, and the exception is "WebDriver Exception":..org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: no element reference returned by script

Comment: may be The page is refreshing after find element and before clicking on it.

Comment: Ohhh. But in that case how to handle that

Comment: You can wait for frame to load. using WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameName);

Comment: Thanks Murthi, but I used it and it is also not working..The Reason Why I am using WebElement saveBtnEle =  sfdcSelFW.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(" div.slds-grid input")); is the element I am trying to find is also under the same shadow root where the iframe is and as per my knowledge we can access shadow elements with the parent shadow element only. and I am following the same process here

Comment: I hope you will find the solution. Once done, please share with us.